# Sorting an array in Simulink

Tags: simulink

I want to sort a given array in ascending order. Is there any block in Simulink which does this? 
If no, how to do this most efficiently using common Simulink blocks? I understand this could be done using Stateflow but just wanted to know how to do in Simulink.
Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you have DSP System toolbox, there is a Sort block available under statistics library. Otherwise you need to use MATLAB Function block as suggested by am304.

Answer (score 1):

Use a [MATLAB Function](http://www.mathworks.co.uk/help/simulink/slref/matlabfunction.html) block in conjunction with the [`sort`](http://www.mathworks.co.uk/help/matlab/ref/sort.html) function. I think that block supports matrix inputs.